# UWP - PivotItem mouse over change color

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to change the Forground color of a PivotItem Header when Mouse is Over with UWP,I work with windows 10

I tried this code:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="mouseOverColor"
                    Color="Red" />
    </Page.Resources>
<Pivot HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemp}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,10,0">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="Icon.(RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel)" Value="True" />
                            <Setter Target="LabelText.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="Icon" />
                            <Setter Target="LabelText.(RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWith)" Value="Icon" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500" />
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="Icon.(RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel)" Value="True" />
                            <Setter Target="LabelText.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="Icon" />
                            <Setter Target="LabelText.(RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith)" Value="Icon" />
                            <Setter Target="RelativePanel.Margin" Value="0,0,12,0"/>
                            <Setter Target="Icon.Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Pivot.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="PivotItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotItem">
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                  Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background"
                   Value="{StaticResource mouseOverColor}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Pivot.Resources>
            <PivotItem Header="/images/img.png" Margin="12,10,12,0"  >
                <Grid>
                    .....
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
```

I have an error "The attachable property "Triggers" was not found in in type 'ControlTemplate'
have you please any idea how can I change the color of an image when the mouse  is over in a universal app
thanks for help

Comment: It might be easier to create two pictures, stack them and show/hide according to mouse over. Or make a single picture, use a transparent color for the foreground parts, stack it on top of a rectangle and change the rectangle's fill based on mouse over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the color of an image, I think it can not be done in the XAML designer, you can do it like this:

XAML code:

```
    <Pivot>
        <PivotItem>
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <Image x:Name="headerimg" Source="Assets/1.jpg" PointerEntered="pointerEntered" PointerExited="pointerExited"/>
            </PivotItem.Header>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
```

key code behind in .cs file:

```
private async void pointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile imgFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets\\1.jpg"));
    using(IRandomAccessStream streamIn = await imgFile.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        //decoder the img
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(BitmapDecoder.JpegDecoderId, streamIn);
        //get pixel
        PixelDataProvider proved = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, new BitmapTransform(),
            ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);
        byte[] srcData = proved.DetachPixelData();

        // GRAYSCALE
        for (int i = 0; i < srcData.Length; i += 4)
        {
            double b = srcData[i]; //B
            double g = srcData[i + 1]; //G
            double r = srcData[i + 2]; //R
            //average
            double v = (r + g + b) / 3d;
            //replace old rgb
            srcData[i] = srcData[i + 1] = srcData[i + 2] = Convert.ToByte(v);
        }

        WriteableBitmap wbimg = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
        srcData.CopyTo(wbimg.PixelBuffer);
        this.headerimg.Source = wbimg;
    }

}

private async void pointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile imgFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets\\1.jpg"));
    IRandomAccessStream streamIn = await imgFile.OpenReadAsync();
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.SetSource(streamIn);
    this.headerimg.Source = bitmap;
}
```

To change the color of an image, you need to decode this image, get its `RGB` values, rewrite these values and turn them back to an image. And there is no `Foreground` property for an `Image` control.

Comment: thanks GraceF for your reply,I have a question please in your reply only one image,if I have 4 images,so should I use an array,then apply the decodation on each image in the array?

Comment: Use an array for what? You mean use an array to collect the addresses of four images? Each time your mouse is on the header, you want to change the color of 4 images together? Or each time change one image? Whatever, you can wrap this `changecolor` code to a function, and call this function each time you get a image file.

Comment: ok thanks GraceF,I will use a function,I have 4 images I want to wrap the change color for each image