# Button Icon tinting in uwp

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a button and there is an icon in it with white color. How can I change the color of the icon with XAML?

Android supports tinting an ImageView like this:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size" android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size" android:src="@drawable/btn_home" android:tint="@{@android:color/black}" />
```

How can I do this in XAML/UWP?

---

**My code**

Resources file:

```
 <Image x:Key="icon_home" Stretch="Fill" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ToolbarIcons/drawable-xhdpi/btn_home.png"/>
```

Page file:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Resources/Images.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

---

```
<Button Width="40" Height="40" Content="{StaticResource icon_home}" />
```

Comment: The icon is an image file, so you can't (easily) change its color. You may probably better use a Path with a Geometry as icon.

Comment: @Clemens thanks but how can I use path, I do not know how to use it to solve that problem. This is very simple in android platform like that          **<ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_icon_size"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_home"
            android:tint="@{@android:color/black}" />**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Grace Feng mentioned, there is no way you can dynamically tint a Button (or any element) like Android allows (at least not easily). In UWP, it's usually best to use vector assets instead of bitmaps because they can scale to any resolution without loss of clarity and *can* be dynamically colored.

I have some alternate suggestions:

**Use a [SymbolIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbolicon.aspx)**

```
<Button Foreground="Red">
    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Home"/>
</Button>
```

[image: SymbolIcon button screenshot]

You can choose the image to display from the [Symbol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol.aspx) enumeration. UWP comes with lots of suitable icons to choose from out of the box. The foreground of the SymbolIcon will be inherited from the Button.

One annoying thing about SymbolIcon is that if you want to change its size, you'll need to wrap it in a [Viewbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox.aspx) and set the size of the Viewbox.

**Use a [FontIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.fonticon.aspx)**

```
<Button Foreground="Red" FontSize="30">
    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE80F;"/>
</Button>
```

[image: FontIcon button screenshot]

The FontIcon class allows you to choose a suitable font which contains the icons you want to display. Windows 10 comes with the Segoe MDL2 Assets font built-in. You can find the glyphs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font). It also respects the FontSize property, which is nice.

**Use a [PathIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pathicon.aspx)**

If you want to use a completely custom icon, this class allows you to display an image from path data.

```
<Button Foreground="Red">
    <PathIcon Data="M0,20 L10,0 L20,20 Z" Width="20" Height="20"/>
</Button>
```

[image: PathIcon button screenshot]

You need to provide the [path markup syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/move-draw-commands-syntax) that defines the icon geometry. This is basically the same as the markup used in SVG images, so it shouldn't be to difficult to obtain this information from a simple SVG asset.

You'll also need to use a Viewbox (or RenderTransform) to change its size.

Comment: Is there a way to fill the icon of a `SymbolIcon`, i.e. fill the home with a color?

Comment: @ShimmyWeitzhandler Unless there is a filled version of the home icon, no.

Answer (score 5):

You should use BitmapIcon instead od Image. This way you don't have to use vectors, but you can tint it. You don't have to use the full path"ms-appx:///Assets/ToolbarIcons/drawable-xhdpi" instead you can just type "Assets/..."

```
<BitmapIcon x:Name="icon_home" UriSource="Assets/ToolbarIcons/drawable-xhdpi/btn_home.png" Foreground="Red"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Clemens said, your icon is an image file, there are many ways changing its color, but I think the most easiest way is replacing this image source with another one.

I saw your comment, maybe what you want is to make the image white and black, in UWP there is no such easy way as it in Andriod, if you insist to use an image and change its color in code, then here is one method, you can refer to my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278840/uwp-pivotitem-mouse-over-change-color/34282506#34282506).

Another fairly simple method is that you can use [Lumia Imaging SDK 3.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt598502.aspx), [GrayscaleEffect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lumia.imaging.adjustments.grayscaleeffect.aspx) is possible what you need.